# I can not return data with useSelector in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want save all input values in redux with dispatch and with useSelector return all data that saved in redux , in redux I create an object and that object have many objects , but I can not return data from redux with useSelector :

```
 import React , { useState } from 'react';
 import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
 import {ButtonForm} from '../../partComponents/button';
 import Input from '../../partComponents/input';
 import { createStore } from 'redux'

 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
 import {ActionCreators} from '../../redux/constants/profile';
 import { reducer } from '../../redux/reducer/profile'
 import { useDispatch , useSelector } from 'react-redux'


 const Signin = () =>{

 const dispatch = useDispatch();

const selector = useSelector(state => state.reducer);

const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();


const onSubmit = data => {
    dispatch(ActionCreators.addProfile(data))
    // console.log(s.getState())
};

  
return(
    <section className="section-signin">
        <div className="app__header">
            <img src={anarLogo} className="app__header--logo" alt="header logo" />
        </div>
        <form className='signin__form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Input
                register={register} 
                inputName='Email'
                inputType='text'
                inputClass='form__input--text' 
                inputPlaceholder='Email'
                inputErrors = {errors}
                inputLabel = 'email'
                rules={{ required: true, minLength: 5
                }}
            />                   
              <Input
                register={register} 
                inputName='Full Name'
                inputType='text'
                inputClass='form__input--text' 
                inputPlaceholder='Full Name'
                inputErrors = {errors}
                inputLabel = 'fullname'
                rules={{ required: true, maxLength: 30, minLength: 3
                }}
            />                   

            <Input 
                register={register}
                inputName='Username'
                inputType='text'
                inputClass='form__input--text'
                inputPlaceholder='Username'
                inputErrors = {errors}
                inputLabel = 'username'
                rules={{ required: true, maxLength: 20, minLength: 3
                }}
            />

            <Input 
                register={register}
                inputName='Password'
                inputType='password'
                inputClass='form__input--password'
                inputPlaceholder='Password'
                inputErrors = {errors}
                inputLabel = 'password'
                rules={{ required: true, maxLength: 20, minLength: 8 ,
                pattern: {
                    value: new RegExp("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])"),
                    message: 'Password must contain at least one letter or number'
                }
                }}
            />

            <ButtonForm 
                buttonValue='Submit' 
                buttonType='submit' 
                buttonClass='form__button--white'
            />
            <p className='signin__message'>Have an account? <Link className='signin__message--link' to='/login'>Log in</Link></p>
```

here I want print fullname of user that assigned in website:

```
          <h1>hello {selector.profile.fullname}</h1>
        </form>
    </section>
  )
 }
```

my reducer file :

```
      import { Types } from '../constants/actionTypes';
      import { createStore } from 'redux'



     const initialState = {
       profile : {
       email: '',
       fullname: '',
       username: '',
       password: ''
     },
      formSubmitted: false
    }

    export const reducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
     switch(action.type){
       case Types.ADD_USER:
        console.log('sing In' , action.payload.user);
        return{
            ...state,
            profile: action.payload.user,
            formSubmitted: false
        }

    case Types.LOGIN:
        console.log('login' , action.payload.user)
        return{
            ...state,
            profile: action.payload.user,
            formSubmitted: false
        }
    case Types.FORM_SUBMITION_STATUS:
        return {
            ...state,
            formSubmitted: action.payload.status
        }
    default:
        return state;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector returns a partial state, `state => state.reducer` has no meaning since your state doesn't have any `reducer` part.

Since you want to return all your state, just select it:

```
const state = useSelector(state => state);
state.profile.fullname
```